# Categories already saved in a product appear empty when editing that same product

Tags: magento2, category, error, empty

When trying to edit a product in Magento 2, the categories that are already saved in the product do not appear, they are empty. If we save without reselecting the categories, then the product is without them, so we need to reselect the categories every time we edit a product.
[image]

Comment: what Magento edition and version are you using, Fabio?

Comment: Hi @DianaBotean, I am using version 2.3.3.

Comment: Is it possible that you have some 3rd party modules changing the Magento behaviour here?

Comment: Hi @DianaBotean no, we left only the magento_ module active, all others are disabled.

Comment: [RESOLVED] Go to database and open eav_attribute table edit attribute_id (105 category_ids) and add backend_model -> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Categor.